# how to solve error Can not execute "qemu"

Tags: pintos

I am doing my home work assignment on pintos. for set up i am following [this](https://learningcage.com/how-to-install-pintos-in-your-machine/) .
On running

```
./pintos run alarm-multiple
```

I got the error

```
Can't exec "qemu": No such file or directory at ./pintos line 923.
command failed
```

How can i solve the error ?

Comment: looks like you didn't follow the previous step..

Comment: I followed and tried multiple time(i was using ubuntu 19.10) and got the same error but when tried in ubuntu 18.04, there is no error now. did not understand what was the problem.